# Convenient way to include equations in pstricks?

Tags: pstricks

For example, I want something of the form

```
$\circle =\frac{[2][3]}{[6]}$,
```

but where the "circle is actually `\pscircle(x,y){r}`.

I have seen the `minipage` environment solution, but the trouble is that, I need a pretty long list of such `picture=numerical value` types of equations, preferably where some appear side by side, which the minipage environment solution doesn't seem optimal for. Is there an easy way to insert equations in the `pstricks picture` environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide *complete*  examples and not only fragments.

```
\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
\pscircle(2,4){1}\rput[l](3,4){ $=\frac{[2][3]}{[6]}$}
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how best to ask the question. This is perfect, thank you